# Is there any way to decompile a fortran exe?

Tags: matlab, fortran, reverse-engineering

Using a Matlab Wrapper I can access all the code's functionalities (MODTRAN exe distributed by Ontar Corporation) but I would like to know what it does in particular and how it communicates with some stored data (they are used to show different plots)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour]. What do you mean by "decompile"? Do you want to see the Fortran source or the assembly code? The former is not possible, the latter is trivial.